# Trying To Incorporate Tokens Into Sign Up

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a token from JWT when a user signs up for my application but I get the error, **Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**. I think there is an issue with the structure of my code. How can I fix this issue?

```
//sign up request
exports.signup = async (req, res, next)=> {
    
    const {email} = req.body;
    const userExist = await User.findOne({email});

    if (userExist) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Email already exists`, 404))
    }

    
    try {
        const user = await User.create(req.body);
        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            user
        })

        generateToken(user, 201, res);


    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
       next(error);
    }
}

//generate token method
const generateToken = async (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = await user.jwtGenerateToken();
    var hour = 3600000;
    const options = {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + hour)
    };
    res.status(statusCode)
    .cookie('token', token, options)
    .json({success: true, token})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate the token and next send the response

```
 generateToken(user, 201, res);

 res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            user
        })
```

You can return value from the token and then send it using response or you can just send it from the `generateToken` function. Here you are trying to use the response again though you have sent it once hence resulting in error.

**Updated**

//sign up request

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next)=> {
        
    const {email} = req.body;
    const userExist = await User.findOne({email});

    if (userExist) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Email already exists`, 404))
    }

    
    try {
        const user = await User.create(req.body);
        generateToken(user, 201, res);


    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
       next(error);
    }
}

//generate token method
const generateToken = async (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = await user.jwtGenerateToken();
    var hour = 3600000;
    const options = {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + hour)
    };
    res.status(statusCode)
        .cookie('token', token, options)
        .json({success: true, token: token, user: user})
}
```

Comment: I tried generating the token before the response but that gives me the same error as to your second method what do you mean returning it and sending a response?

Comment: in your generate token method just generate the token and return the generated token back to the origin that is from where generateToken is being called. Capture the generated token. And then in your response inject the token and send a single response to the client. Here you are sending response twice. One from the generateToken function and other from the origin. Just send a single response . It should work.

Comment: You can either use just the generateToken function as you are already sending the response from that method. In this case there is no need to send the response again from the signup. 

Or you can as i have previously said, just return the token from the function to signup and send the response from signup

Comment: @BStorm i have updated the answer adding code for a single http request.  You haven't cleared which JSON would you want but hopefully this single response will work for you, and you can easily restructure the JSON as you want

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send the response twice. and then in generateToken method. Keep it at one place, the error will go away.